# Save iteration values from list to single object

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to store in one object many values from list using for loop. All are of FloatField type. My function gives me many objects with one result. I need just one object with all values in one row.

views.py

```
namesOfModelFields = [f.name for f in ModelName._meta.get_fields()]
resultsOfNames = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
resultsOfValue - ['1','2','3']
form = f_Form()
newF = form.save(commit=False)
for i in namesOfModelFields:
    if any(str(i) in s for s in resultsOfNames):
        j = resultsOfValue[resultsOfNames.index(i)]
        form = f_Form({str(i) : float(j)})
        newF = form.save(commit=False)
        newF.save()
if form.is_valid():
    form.save_m2m()
```

forms.py

```
class f_Form(ModelForm):

  class Meta:
   model = ModelName
   fields = '__all__'
```

models.py

```
class ModelName (models.Model):

 name1 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
 name2 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
 name3 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I have much more fileds than 3. I can't do this one by one

Comment: What does "one object with all values in one row" mean? What result are you hoping to get?

Comment: https://i.imgsafe.org/512aacd7e2.png
This is a result in my db. I want to have all values in one row.

Comment: So why are you instantiating a new form in each iteration? In fact why are you doing any of this?

Comment: it is the last version I tried. When newF.save() isn't in for loop it save only last record. I try also create two list in for loop and after that save it in form 
newF.iList = iListNum 
but it also don't work

Comment: But you don't have a list here, and I don't understand why you even have a loop. Maybe you should post your model definition and an example of exactly what is in `namesOfModelField`, `resultsOfNames` and `resultsOfValue`, as well as explaining where they are coming from.

Comment: update. I have much more models and values to insert. I can't do this one by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't understand anything that you're doing. But if you just want to create a single model instance, then do that, and don't muck about with forms or loops.

```
values = dict(zip(resultsOfNames, resultsOfValues))
new_item = ModelName.objects.create(**values))
```

Comment: because i finding words in doc and compare it with names in models